# LightDM and introductory screen

Tags: screen, lightdm

How can I set original introductory screen and LightDM, they changed after installing the system administrator KDE.

Comment: Run 'sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm' to set the default display manager (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM)...

I do not know what you mean with the "introductory screen", sry...